# Standardizing dataset before comparing slopes in regression

Tags: regression, anova, lm, partial-least-squares

I have 3 different yield parameters data which was obtained from four different locations. Here is the distribution of dataset at all locations.

[image]

I want to determine which yield component is strongly influenced by the disease. I am planning to analyze my data using the following code:

```
slopes <- lm(Yield ~ AUDPC * Component* Farm, data = Patch)
anova(slopes)

# Obtain slopes
slopes$coefficients

slopes.lst <- lstrends(slopes, "Component", var="AUDPC")
slopes.lst

pairs(slopes.lst)
```

However, as the yield parameters are different from each other. Should I standardize my dataset first?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can standardize your data before running the regression OR run the regression without standardization and look for the one with the highest standardized coefficients.

You can get standardized coefficients using [this package](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/lm.beta/lm.beta.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Kasa. It is much easier than standardizing the data.

Comment: @Ramay: you are welcome! If this solved your problem, consider accepting the answer.